# python and ghost crash

Tags: python, pyside, qtcore, ghost

I'm trying to get ghost to work with python and have followed instructions for installation on http://ghostpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but as soon as I run

```
from ghost import Ghost
gh = Ghost
```

it throws the error

> Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

When I run

```
import PySide
print(PySide.QtCore.__version__)
print(PySide.__version__)
```

it gives me

```
4.8.5
1.2.2
```

suggesting both QTCore and PySide are installed according to instructions. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?

I'm using Python 3.4 and together with pycharm 4.0.5.

Answer (score 4):

You typed `gh = Ghost` without parentheses `()`. It should be as such:

```
gh = Ghost()
```

From the docs:

```
from ghost import Ghost

url = "http://www.ebay.com/"
gh = Ghost() #RIGHT HERE

# We load the main page of ebay
page, resources = gh.open(url, wait_onload_event=True)

# Full the main bar and click on the search button
gh.set_field_value("#gh-ac", "plane")
gh.click("#gh-btn")

# Wait for the next page
gh.wait_for_selector("#e1-15")

# Save the image of the screen
gh.capture_to("plane.png")
```